# How do I append items from a list to another stopping at a specific value?

Tags: python

I'm building a game of Othello, so I have a list of coordinates that are either `b` or `w` on the board.

For example I have lists of coordinates within a list as such

```
list_a = [ [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6]], [[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]], [[3,5],[2,5],[1,5]] ]
```

---

list 1 is `[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6]] ### [1,4] is 'b' everything else is 'w'`

list 2 is `[[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]] ### everything is 'w', no 'b'`

third list is `[[3,5],[2,5],[1,5]] ### [1,5] is 'b'`

---

```
list_b = []
```

I want to add all the coordinates that are  `w` into `list_b` stopping at `b`, but I don't want to append any `w` if it doesn't have a `b` after it.

Ideally, I want my `list_b` to be

```
[ [[1,2],[1,3]], [[3,5],[2,5]] ]
```

I don't mind if it's

```
[ [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]], [[3,5],[2,5],[1,5] ]
```

I can just remove the `b` coordinates later.

---

What's the best way to do this? I'm currently building this within a class and using `for` loops, `while True`, `if` statements etc.

Comment: Sounds like you want something along the lines of `itertools.takewhile()`.

Answer (score 0):

You never stated what the board was or how the coordinates are connected to it (perhaps something like `[1, 4]` for `board[1][4] == 'b'`?), so I'll just use the string values you're referring to, e.g. `'wwbww'` instead of `[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6]]`.

```
import itertools
list_a = ['wwbww', 'www', 'wwb']
result = [list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x!='b', item)) for item in list_a if 'b' in item]
```

Result:

```
>>> result
[['w', 'w'], ['w', 'w']]
```

`result` is a `list` comprehension where each item first checks if it contains a `'b'` (since you only want the `'w'`s if there's a `'b'` in there somewhere), and then creates a `list` out of an `itertools.takewhile()` call. This function grabs every element from an iterable until the given function returns a falsey value. To expand:

```
import itertools

def okay_to_add(x):
    return x != 'b'

result = []
for item in list_a:
    if 'b' in item:
        temp = []
        for c in itertools.takewhile(okay_to_add, item):
            temp.append(c)
        result.append(temp)
```

The result is identical.

You'll have to create an `okay_to_add` function of your own that, instead of a simple `x != 'b'`, looks up the given coordinate in the board and returns whether it's the `'b'` (or `'w'`, for the other player) that you're interested in.

Comment: You're correct the values is just board[x][y] = 'b' or 'w'
The thing is that I don't want to add any 'w' (opponents turn) after the first 'b' (my turn). And if there isn't a 'b' following the 'w' then I don't want to append those coordinates into my new list.

Comment: @Carl - That is what it's doing. `result` is the first two `'w'`s from the first `list` (`[1,2]` and `[1,3]`), then nothing from the second one, then both `'w'`s from the third one (`[3,5]` and `[2,5]`).

Comment: Thanks TigerhawkT3, I didn't catch that!

Comment: @Carl - Glad to hear it. If this answer solved your issue, you can mark it as such by clicking the check mark below its score.